# App comes back to same activity after loggin in with Twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to create Twitter login for my Android app. Once I log in, I change the twitter btn title from "Connect with Twitter" to "Disconnect Twitter" and I write out my Twitter username. The only strange thing is that if now I click BACK to quit the application, I go back to where I was before, meaning the button says "Connect with Twitter" againand my Twitter username is not displayed. I am logged in, because if now I click BACK again, I quit the app (go back to the Twitter auth page first) and when I open the app again, the session lives, and the button says "Disconnect Twitter".

Why?

```
public class Activity_Splash extends Activity {
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
     private static Twitter twitter;
     private static RequestToken requestToken;
     private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
     private AccessToken accessToken;
     User user;
     String twitter_username = "";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(TwitterConst.PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Log.i("Splash start", "Twitter is NOT connected");
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TwitterConst.CALLBACK_URL)) {
                final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(TwitterConst.IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                new Connect_Twitter().execute(verifier);
         } else {
            Log.i("Splash start", "Twitter is connected");
         }


if (isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            btn_signupTW.setText("Disconnect Twitter");
            btn_signupTW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    disconnectTwitter();
                }
            });
        } else {
            btn_signupTW.setText("Connect with Tw");
            btn_signupTW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    connectTwitter();
                }
            });
        }

private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
            return mSharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_TOKEN, null) != null;
        }

        private void connectTwitter() {
            Log.i("Twitter", "connectTwitter()");
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterConst.CONSUMER_KEY);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterConst.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
            twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterConst.CALLBACK_URL);
                        Log.i("Twitter connectTwitter", "Please authorize this app!");
                        Activity_Splash.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Twitter connectTwitter", e.getMessage() + "");
                    }
                }
             });
            thread.start();   
        }

private void disconnectTwitter() {
            Log.i("Twitter", "disconnectTwitter()");
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            e.remove(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_TOKEN);
            e.remove(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_SECRET);
            e.commit();
            btn_signupTW.setText("Connect with Tw");
            tv_slogan.setText("Log in with Facebook");
        }
```

public class Connect_Twitter extends AsyncTask {

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
            Log.i("SIKER", result + "");
            tv_slogan.setText(result);
            btn_signupTW.setText("Disconnect Twitter");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, params[0]); 
                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token1", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.putString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken()); 
                e.putString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret()); 
                e.commit();

                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                Log.i("Twitter userID", String.valueOf(userID) + "");
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                twitter_username = user.getName();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            return twitter_username;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

1. Before calling `SettingsActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));` I save the current activity in Sharedpreferences
2. When the splash activity comes up (the main that opens every time I open the app) I check this variable in Sharedpreferences and if it's true then I open up SettingsActivity and send the verifier with the intent.
3. In SettingsActivity now it's easy to log in with this verifier and get user data.

SplashActivity:

```
if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
boolean fromSettingsActivity = mSharedPreferences2.getBoolean(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS, false);
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TwitterConst.CALLBACK_URL)) {
        final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(TwitterConst.IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
        if (fromSettingsActivity) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Splash.this, SettingsActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("verifier", verifier);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
           return;
        } else {    
           new Connect_Twitter().execute(verifier);
        }
    }
}
```

SettingsActivity:

```
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle extras = iin.getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String verifier = extras.getString("verifier");
    new Connect_Twitter().execute(verifier);
}
```

And don't forget to reset the Sharedpreferences value when you click BACK:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mSharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences2.edit();
    e.remove(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS);
    e.commit();
    super.onBackPressed();    
}
```

One more thing

With the current intent the app opens up the SettingsActivity again, so you need to click BACK two times. This is the default behaviour of the Twitter login. To prevent this, use the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter just launched Fabric, a set of SDKs with several services to mobile developers. One of them is Twitter kit, it provides Sign in with Twitter, Tweet composing, Embedded tweets and API calls directly from the SDK.

Instead of trying to implement this OAuth flow in your app, Sign in with Twitter with this SDK can be integrated this way:

```
private void setUpTwitterButton() {
    twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
    twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            SessionRecorder.recordSessionActive("Login: twitter account active", result.data);
            startThemeChooser();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_twitter_signin_fail),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Crashlytics.logException(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

You can find more details about that at:

- http://t.co/fabric
- https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android (sample android app)
- https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login

To get access to Fabric: fabric.io

Comment: Thanks for the advertisement, but no. First of all this does not answer the question. Second, I signed up and I got on a waiting list. Will you remove OAuth in the future in preference of this Fabric thing?